# How to force quit Applescript app from terminal?

Tags: applescript

I wrote an applescript that turns on my lights. I exported it as an application with the name "LightsOn", and it appears with that name in activity monitor.

[image: LightsOn in Activity Monitor]

Under certain circumstances, this app gets stuck. I can force quit it from Activity Monitor, but I want to be able to do so from a script. `killall LightsOn` doesn't work; I'm told that `no matching processes belonging to you were found`.

How can properly force quit this app from the terminal? Or, how can I discover the appropriate name for killall?

Comment: `pkill -9 -f LightsOn` will do it!

Comment: @user3439894 Yay, that was easy! I've been trying to figure out how to do this for ages. If you make that an answer, I'll accept it!

Comment: As requested, I posted an answer covering my comment to you that worked over the other answer which originally didn't, but has since been edited. I added additional information to cover why `killall LightsOn` doesn't work.

Comment: Instead of needing a kill why not code a timeout in your app?

Comment: @ʀ2ᴅ2 Long story, but the short version is because (1) this is an invisible helper application, so it doesn't matter much, and (2) there's no good way to set a timeout for a shell script in an Applescript, and what is doable is finicky and error prone.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason `killall LightsOn` doesn't work is because all running **AppleScript** application's process name is `applet`. For example, the executable path is:

```
../LightsOn.app/Contents/MacOS/applet
```

In general and assuming the process(es) is(are) not hung, one could use `killall applet` however that will terminate all running **AppleScript** applications, and of course that may not be desirable.

When a process is hung, you'll need to use a `KILL` *signal*, e.g.:

```
killall -KILL applet
```

However, **`pkill`** is the way to go to easily target a specific **AppleScript** application and because it's hung... use a `KILL` *signal*, e.g.:

```
pkill -9 -f LightsOn
```

Or:

```
pkill -KILL -f LightsOn
```

Note in this instance, `-9` is just another way of saying `-KILL`.

Now with **`pkill`** and using the `-f` *option*, one can use more of the *full argument list*, e.g.:

```
pkill -9 -f /Applications/LightsOn.app/Contents/MacOS/applet
```

Then there's no ambiguity as to which `applet` *process* one is targeting. One can use as much of the *full argument list* as one feels is necessary to target the correct *process*.

For example, `pkill -9 -f LightsOn` will terminate an **AppleScript** application named `NoLightsOn`, so always use enough of the *full argument list* to terminate the correct process.

---

For reference:

From the `pkill` man page:

> ```
>  -f          Match against full argument lists.  The default is to match
>              against process names.
> ```

From the `killall` man page:

> ```
>  Some of the more commonly used signals:
>
>  1       HUP (hang up)
>  2       INT (interrupt)
>  3       QUIT (quit)
>  6       ABRT (abort)
>  9       KILL (non-catchable, non-ignorable kill)
>  14      ALRM (alarm clock)
>  15      TERM (software termination signal)
> ```

<sub>Note that this is just a partial *signal* list and is used with many of the different utilities that can terminate a process. See the various manual pages of the utilities used for additional information.</sub>

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

`ps auxwww | fgrep -v fgrep | fgrep -i LightsOn`

That should show you the matching process information.

You can also try `pkill` which should work like this:

`pgrep -fl LightsOn`

If that shows you the PID, then you can move on to `pkill`:

`pkill -9 -f LightsOn`

When you run pkill -9, you're not telling the application to terminate itself, instead you're telling the OS to stop running the program, no matter what the program is doing.

When app gets stuck sending the `kill` without specifying the signal #, it will automatically assign to it the signal <15>, which means asking the app to terminate it self, it can not do that while stuck.

Comment: You said, Try this: `ps auxwww | fgrep -v fgrep | fgrep -I LightsOn`, why!? when `pkill -9 -f LightsOn` will do it!

Comment: `pkill -fl LightsOn` isn't killing the app on my machine. I seem to need the -9.

Comment: @user3439894 The first command was never intended to kill the process, just to show its information, which might help explain why `killall` wasn't doing what was expected. `pkill -9` is a blunt instrument, not a first step. IMO.